# sphinx indexer is not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, sphinx

i want to index MSSql 2008 database in windows 7.
this is my config file

```
source main
{

    type                    = mssql

    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user        = sa
    sql_pass        = pass
        #mssql_winauth      = 1
    sql_db                  = article
    sql_port                = 1433  # optional, default is 3306




    mssql_unicode       = 1 # request Unicode data from server

    sql_query_pre = insert into IndexLog(StartDateTime, Count, Successful) select top 1 getdate(), (select COUNT(id) from article),0 from article

    sql_query   = SELECT ID ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Title) AS TitleRowNo\
                ,Title,abstract \
                FROM article
    #Log index end
    sql_query_post_index = update IndexLog set EndDateTime = getdate(), successful = 1 where id = (select max(id) from IndexLog)


    sql_attr_uint = ID
    sql_attr_uint = TitleRowNo


}

index news_main
{
    source                  = main
    path                    = C:/sphinx/article/data/news_main
    docinfo                 = extern
    charset_type            = utf-8


    min_word_len        = 3
    min_infix_len       = 3
    infix_fields    = Title, abstract
#   min_stemming_len = 0
#   index_exact_words = 1
}



indexer
{
    mem_limit               = 32M
}


searchd
{
    port                    = 6550 # 9312
    log                     = C:/sphinx/article/log/searchd.log
    query_log               = C:/sphinx/article/log/query.log
    read_timeout            = 5
    max_children            = 0 # concurrent searches to run in parallel 
    pid_file                = C:/sphinx/article/log/searchd.pid
    max_matches             = 1000
    seamless_rotate         = 1
    preopen_indexes         = 0
    unlink_old              = 1

    collation_server        = utf8_general_ci
    collation_libc_locale   = utf8_general_ci
}
```

i use this command to run index.

`indexer --config "C:\sphinx\a.sphinx.conf" news_main`

but is not work.

Comment: Please be more specific - 'how' exactly does it not work....

Comment: sql_query_pre = insert into IndexLog(StartDateTime, Count, Successful) select top 1 getdate(), (select COUNT(id) from article),0 from article.
it is not work. and index file not create. without any error.

Comment: What output DOES indexer give you when you run the above command?

Comment: is not give me any output.

Comment: Then I humbly suggest you are not even running the command. Perhaps you are not in the right folder

Comment: Indexer become start and indexer process add to my system process. it means command is running.but after many seconds process become stop without any action.

Comment: Sorry, but extracting little snippets of information out of you just isnt working. If you want help suggest you start again and thoughlly document what is and isnt happening.

Comment: dear Barryhunter, thank you for your follow up. and excuse me for my english.